# How to define shorcuts for the tasks package with \def?

Tags: macros, tasks

I tried to define the shortcuts

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}

\def\bqcmt{\begin{tasks}(2)}
\def\eqcmt{\end{tasks}}
\def\myitem{\task}

\begin{document}
\bqcmt
\myitem This is a test
\eqcmt
\end{document}
```

But it does not work. The error is:

> LaTeX Error: \begin{tasks} on input line 10 ended by \end {document}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.13 \end{document}
> ```

Why is it so? How can I define such shorcuts?

## A solution ?

The following seems to work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\def\bqcmt{\csname tasks\endcsname(3)}
\def\eqcmt{\endtasks}
\def\myitem{\csname endtasks\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\bqcmt
\task This is a test
\task This is a test
\task This is a test
\eqcmt
\end{document}
```

as well as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\newcommand{\bqcmt}[1]{\csname tasks\endcsname(#1)}
\def\eqcmt{\endtasks}
\def\myitem{\csname endtasks\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\bqcmt{3}
\task This is a test
\task This is a test
\task This is a test
\eqcmt
\end{document}
```

## My new question ?

But I'm wondering if it is a good idea. Indeed, `\begin{tasks}` will normally scan the rest of the file for an `\end{tasks}`. With this "hack", I guess that this scan will not happen.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `\myitem` seems totally pointless but for reasons I don't show in this MWE it is not. Actually I have others commands that changes the definitions of `\myitem` depending on the context. That's why I create this shortcut.

Comment: Never do you, you even up with a poor sematics and code that is hard to read. Instead look into the features of your editor. Most editors today have the ability to insert small templates at a press of a button, thus one key stroke and you have all this written for you

Comment: Thanks @daleif I know, of course. But I don't want to use these features (for very good reasons) and I want to redefine some shorcuts to `\begin{tasks}(2)`, `\end{tasks}` and `\task`.

Comment: Then please explain those reasons? And why an inferior syntax is better? You will see it again and again here that we never recommend doing this. BTW did you try the standard trick of using the macro form of the environment? aka `\tasks{2}` and `\endtasks` (untested)

Comment: The TeX engine doesn't know what an environment is.  It simply expands macros. IIRC, `\begin` is simply `\csname #1\endcsname` and `\end` is `\csname end#1\endcsname`.

Comment: Great @JohnKormylo. It works! If you wish to make your comment an answer, please do it!

Comment: The problem is \task is doing some nasty things. `\meaning\task` yields `end-group character } `  I suspect \task is not a macro, but rather is a token list.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have edited my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: \begin only uses \csname because the name is passed as an argument.  \tasks is fine.

Comment: Could you say a few words why you added a bounty to this question? Your edits already seem to solve your problem

Comment: @siracusa: Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad idea.

Anyway, you can use a macro with delimited argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\long\def\bqcmt#1#2\eqcmt{\begin{tasks}(#1)#2\end{tasks}}

\begin{document}

\bqcmt{3}
\task a
\task b
\task c
\task d
\task e
\task f
\eqcmt

\bigskip

\begin{tasks}(3)
\task a
\task b
\task c
\task d
\task e
\task f
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can define a “new task” for using `\item` as a separator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasks{colastasks}[\item]

\long\def\bqcmt#1#2\eqcmt{\begin{colastasks}(#1)#2\end{colastasks}}

\begin{document}

\bqcmt{3}
\item a
\item b
\item c
\item d
\item e
\item f
\eqcmt

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it also possible to redefine `\task` to `\myitem` or, better, to `\item`? Thanks

Comment: @Colas It just takes reading the manual.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I tried various ways to define "`\item=\task`" but didn't think of reading the manual. Thanks a lot !